# Is it possible to deduce the value of a string when given its hash and multiples hashes of the string + other known strings?

Tags: hash, preimage-resistance

To be clear, I have access to $H(S)$ and as many $H(S||K)$ as I want. Every string $K$ is known. Can I use the extra information to my advantage and try to deduce $S$, without requiring bruteforce? Or do you still have to bruteforce but try less combinations since you have more information?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the hash is strong, you will not be able to find a preimage any more easily when you know multiple hashes (whether they use the same function or [another](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/does-knowing-multiple-hash-of-the-same-content-make-it-more-likely-to-generate-o)). In fact, with some hashes you will be able to derive $H(S||K)$ from just $H(S)$ and $K$ (known as the length extension attack), so it can't give you more information.

Unless the hash is broken, the only way to find $S$ in either case is to guess, hash and compare.

However, if your hash was short enough to have collisions, you could need multiple hash values to verify a guess. As an extreme example, consider the first byte truncation of a strong hash. Any guess you make will match it one 256th the time. In that case, knowing more hashes would allow you to verify your guess with higher confidence.